# What is an inline script?

Tags: security, inline, policy

This is a bit of a simple question but I have looked around the internet and Stack Overflow and I can't find anyone to just state the answer directly.

What is an inline script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is referring to sql script. So rather than use a stored procedure, you may choose to inline the sql in your code, like this:

string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable";

But, you can apply this to other things. Anytime you hardcode something of this nature, it is considered inline if you could have defined it externally. Javascript for instance. You can add a script block and add javascript 'inline' or you can consolidate your script into an external .js file.

IMO, inline just means you hard-coded something that could have been defined externally, like in a config file perhaps that is easier to modify. Or instead of putting your script block at the end, you inserted it right smack in the middle of your html, inline.